# Marantz PMD 661compatibility with Rode MT USB miniUSB

Tags: microphone, recorder

I already had the Rode MT USB mini and just purchased the Marantz PMD 661. Looks like I'll need some type of adapter to use with the Marantz.

Can they work together?

What can I use to bridge them together?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely to the Marantz PMD 661 USB connector, you will see it is a mini USB type B connector. Such a connector is typically made to handle connection from the MIC (USB device) to a PC (USB Host).

Theorically, such a connector can be connected to a USB device (a USB MIC) if the USB On The Go protocol is implemented (like Android phones). But I have seen nowhere in the Marantz Recorder documentation a sign of this use. The manual only describes the USB connector as a way to exchange files between the recorder and a PC.

Then I don't think the Marantz to be compatible with any USB microphone.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual](https://241e516beb3f645a2dcd-039af1276f5bbb1d23d83467ce519c3f.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com//1252/documents/PMD661MK2EM_ENG_manual.pdf), the Marantz has no USB input capability at all. USB is only used to hand off data to a computer. It's a 15-year-old design & well past its sell-by date, technologically. [It can also only use SDHC cards, so it's limited to 32GB]
In USB terminology, it is a 'device' not a 'host'.

The only way to get the mic into the recorder would be by using another machine, computer etc as host, then piping over analog… which doesn't really seem worth the effort.